# Effective user id does not change after making the file owned by root

Tags: command-line, permissions, privileges

I'm currently reading a book on programming with C, I got to a part where I've got to write a program which will display the real uid and effective uid that the file is being executed on. After compiling the code with `gcc`, I input the command to see the current uOwner and gOwner `ls- l id_demo` the output is this:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 8629 Sep 21 13:04 id_demo
```

I then execute the program itself, this is what I get:

```
real uid: 1000 effective uid: 1000
```

...so far so good. I then input a command to change the owner of the file:

```
sudo chown root:root ./id_demo
```

The `ls -l` confirms that the owner has been changed to root:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 8629 Sep 21 13:04 id_demo
```

Again, executing the program shows `real uid` and `uid` as 1000. The last step after which the `uid` must be 0 is this: `sudo chmod u+s ./uid_demo` but for me they stay as 1000, where in the book the output is clearly show to be this:

```
real uid: 1000
effective uid: 0
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

**UPDATE**

id_demo source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("real uid: %d\n", getuid());
    printf("effective uid: %d\n", geteuid());
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
Screen shots

[image: ss #1]

[image: ls -l testuid]

**PLEASE HELP. I'm going crazy I spent 6+hour looking for the solution and I need to move on.**

Comment: It's probably unrelated but for `getuid()` and `geteuid()` you need `unistd.h` and `sys/types.h` which you aren't including. Refer `man 2 getuid`.

Comment: ill try, but the code is from the book.

Comment: same result still damn 1000

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[We've figured it out.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37804/discussion-between-evgeny-danilenko-and-martin-von-wittich) The cause is an `ecryptfs`-mounted home directory. The `mount` output contains the following line:

```
/home/evgeny/.Private on /home/evgeny type ecryptfs
```

That means that the home directory isn't actually part of the root filesystem (that has the necessary `suid` flag), but its own virtual filesystem that apparently doesn't support setuid binaries by default. I have successfully reproduced the issue with a test user that has an encrypted home directory.

It is possible to add the `suid` flag to the ecryptfs with the following command:

```
sudo mount -i -o remount,suid /home/evgeny
```

I'm not certain though how safe that is, nor how to change it permanently so that it would survive reboots.

Comment: This shouldn't of been migrated to SO, this belongs more on U&L. I'll ask the mod about bringing it back.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. You rule!

Comment: @slm Yes, definitely belongs on U&L now that we found out it really was a system-specific issue and not a programming problem.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - FYI, I sent a note to the U&L mod last night asking about migrating it back, waiting to hear back.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

*compile*

```
$ gcc uid_demo.c -o uid_demo

$ ll
total 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 6743 Sep 21 17:05 uid_demo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  116 Sep 21 16:58 uid_demo.c
```

*chown*

```
$ sudo chown root:root uid_demo
$ ll
total 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 6743 Sep 21 17:05 uid_demo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  116 Sep 21 16:58 uid_demo.c
```

*chmod*

```
$ sudo chmod u+s uid_demo
$ ll
total 12
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 6743 Sep 21 17:05 uid_demo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml  116 Sep 21 16:58 uid_demo.c
```

*run*

```
$ ./uid_demo 
real uid: 500
effective uid: 0
```

Comment: how the... why is it not working for me? i've edited fstab and mtab entries so ill have the suid enable and still no result what am i doing wrong?

Comment: ubuntu 13.04. i ad same thought about the increase security with the newer distros..

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko try to move the binary somewhere where you and `others` don't have write access, e.g. to `/usr/local/bin`. It is possible that some security mechanism realizes that you have write access to the folder where your binary is located, and therefore ignores the setuid bit because you would be able to exploit it.

Comment: if i understood you correct you want me to move the compiled code into /usr/local/bin right?

thanks for the reply

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko yes, `sudo mv uid_demo /usr/local/bin`. Then execute it as `uid_demo`.

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko - remember to call it as `/usr/local/bin/uid_demo`.

Comment: I don't know if this'll help as I can't reproduce your issue on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine, but it's a hunch... such a security feature certainly would make sense.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! It worked, ill mark your answer as accepted. But do you know how to make work from my normal dir the Documents folder?

Comment: It's probably impossible then. If it works the way I believe it works (can't find any sources by googling), then the kernel is ensuring that normal users (like your account) don't have write access to the setuid binary. As soon as you put the file into your home, you have write access (at least you can get write access rather easily), and the kernel catches this and ignore the setuid bit to prevent exploits. Which is after all a good thing.

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko, @slm: please post both the output of `uname -a`. I'm curious whether this is a new kernel feature in a more recent Linux version that only EvgenyDanilenko has installed, but not slm and me. Mine is: `Linux martin 3.8.0-30-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 20:52:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: yes true that, so editing the fstab and mtab, remounting the directory was useless?

Comment: I doubt it's impossible, it's probably some mechanism that's blocking the access.

Comment: here it is: 

`Linux b3ast 3.8.0-30-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 20:52:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Linux grinchy 2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 23 13:07:52 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Hm, strange, so we both have the same kernel, but it behaves different? :o

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko check the output of `dmesg` and look through the logs in `/var/log`, especially `syslog`. Maybe there's a hint somewhere what is actually causing this.

Comment: i've looked through the dmesg and syslog, what exactly am i looking for?

Comment: Some kind of security error relating to setuid that occurred during the time where you were trying to execute your test binary.

Comment: these are the only error i found relative to setuid i have at least 4 of those `Sep 21 16:16:50 b3ast gnome-screensaver-dialog: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error` but i dont think it that cuz you know.. gnome screensaver

Comment: Yeah, I've got nothing. I've been googling all the time and I've looked through the Linux sources, but I still haven't the slightest clue what's going on here. Maybe it's something filesystem-related after all? Do you `/home` and `/usr` live on separate filesystems?

Comment: you mean if they are partitioned? no when i installed the os i selected to have "all in one"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37804/discussion-between-evgeny-danilenko-and-martin-von-wittich)